# context3d.setRenderToTexture() performance

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, stage3d

I'm currently developing a 2D game in stage3d. Performance is amazing - I get 60/60 FPS with lots of sprites moving on a screen.

I've started to implement post-processing filters: I would render everything to a texture instead of a screen, apply shaders to it, and then render it back on a screen.

But I faced major performance drop - up to 40 FPS by just using setRenderToTexture with simplest shader.

Maybe I render it the wrong way or the issue is how I render the final texture.

SWF size is 980x600, which makes a final texture 1024x1024.

**Here's my fast and dirty implementation of this post-processing: https://gist.github.com/4616886**

I use Axel engine( http://axgl.org ), but code should be easy to understand for anyone.

Gist shows code I changed in Ax.as ( https://github.com/arkeus/Axel/blob/master/src/org/axgl/Ax.as )

And I use couple of functions from AxCache.as ( https://github.com/arkeus/Axel/blob/master/src/org/axgl/util/AxCache.as )

And here's the SPRITE_INDEX_BUFFER I used -
( https://github.com/arkeus/Axel/blob/master/src/org/axgl/AxSprite.as#L518 )

Answer (score 1):

createTexture(width:int,height:int,format:String,optimizeForRenderToTexture:Boolean,streamingLevels:int = 0)

I can't believe I missed it... hours of googling and trial and error and I missed a constructor parameter.

FPS is back to normal now!